# Currency based on HTTP request getLocale throwing IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, servlets, illegalargumentexception

I am trying to get currency symbols based on locale, currency code in a servlet.

I tried to do the following but it is throwing `IllegalArgumentException`.

```
Currency.getInstance(request.getlocale())
```

Locale has language as "en" but country value empty.

How to get currency symbols for a locale, currency code?

Comment: Please post a code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not make sense to ask for the currency for a locale without a country.

What is the currency for, say, "English", as in your question?  This could be USD (US), AUD (Australia), UKP (United Kingdom), EUR (Ireland), CAD (Canada), etc., etc.  In other words, without knowing the country you cannot pick a currency, and in fact, the currency depends ONLY on the country and never on the language.  Countries have one official currency but can have more than one language, as in  Canada having locales `fr_CA` and `en_CA`.

Also, it's pretty clearly spelled out in the Javadoc (my emphasis):

> ```
> public static Currency getInstance​(Locale locale)
> ```
>
> Returns the Currency instance for the country of the given locale. The language and variant components of the locale are ignored. The result may vary over time, as countries change their currencies. For example, for the original member countries of the European Monetary Union, the method returns the old national currencies until December 31, 2001, and the Euro from January 1, 2002, local time of the respective countries.
>
> The method returns null for territories that don't have a currency, such as Antarctica.
>
> Parameters:
>
> locale - the locale for whose ***country*** a Currency instance is needed
>
> Returns:
>
> the Currency instance for the country of the given locale, or null
> Throws:
>
> NullPointerException - if locale is null
>
> ***IllegalArgumentException - if the country of the given locale is not a supported ISO 3166 country code.***